# Sort pandas dataframe columnin an order that includes duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, sorting

I have produced a sample dataframe below.

```
import pandas as pd

col1=['1M','1M','1M','1M','1M','1M','1M','1M','1M','1M','1M','1M']

col11=['2M','2M','2M','2M','2M','2M','2M','2M','2M','2M','2M','2M']

col111=['3M','3M','3M','3M','3M','3M','3M','3M','3M','3M','3M','3M']    

col1111=['4M','4M','4M','4M','4M','4M','4M','4M','4M','4M','4M','4M']

final_col1=col1+col11+col111+col1111


#col2=['1M','2M','3M','4M','5M','6M','7M','8M','9M','10M','11M','12M']

col2=['1M','2M','3M','4M']


final_col2=12*col2
col22=['1M','2M','3M','4M']

col23=['1M','2M','3M','4M']



df1=pd.DataFrame()

df1['col1']=final_col1

df1['col2']=final_col2
```

I want to sort the dataframe so that the order of 'col1' and 'col2' are interchanged. The real data has more than 1 million rows and other columns so I can't just interchange the 'col1' and 'col2'. Thanking you in advance.

df3 is the expected output:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame()



df2['col2']=final_col1

df2['col1']=final_col2

cols=['col1','col2']
df3=df2[cols]
```

Adding sample input data and oytput data.
Input data

```
  col1 col2  data
0    1M   1M     1
1    1M   2M     2
2    1M   3M     3
3    1M   4M     4
4    1M   1M     5
5    1M   2M     6
6    1M   3M     7
7    1M   4M     8
8    1M   1M     9
9    1M   2M    10
10   1M   3M    11
11   1M   4M    12
12   2M   1M    13
```

Output data:

```
  col1 col2  data
0   1M   1M     1
1   2M   1M    13
```

Comment: How looks expected ouput, e.g. first 12 rows?

Comment: Exactly, not clear what we want to achieve here?

Comment: @jezrael, added the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to sort the values of `col1` based on the order of `col2`.

Assuming you need to match the exact order of `col2` in order of the duplicates, reindex the rows using a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
order = (
 df1[['col2']]
    .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby('col2').cumcount())
    .merge(df1[['col1']].reset_index().assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby('col1').cumcount()),
           left_on=['col2', 'n'], right_on=['col1', 'n'], how='left'
           )
     ['index']
)

out = df1.loc[order]
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2
0    1M   1M
12   2M   1M
24   3M   1M
36   4M   1M
1    1M   2M
13   2M   2M
25   3M   2M
37   4M   2M
2    1M   3M
14   2M   3M
26   3M   3M
38   4M   3M
3    1M   4M
15   2M   4M
27   3M   4M
39   4M   4M
4    1M   1M
16   2M   1M
28   3M   1M
40   4M   1M
5    1M   2M
17   2M   2M
29   3M   2M
41   4M   2M
6    1M   3M
18   2M   3M
30   3M   3M
42   4M   3M
7    1M   4M
19   2M   4M
31   3M   4M
43   4M   4M
8    1M   1M
20   2M   1M
32   3M   1M
44   4M   1M
9    1M   2M
21   2M   2M
33   3M   2M
45   4M   2M
10   1M   3M
22   2M   3M
34   3M   3M
46   4M   3M
11   1M   4M
23   2M   4M
35   3M   4M
47   4M   4M
```

Answer (score 0):

To interchange the order of columns in the pandas DataFrame, you can use the indexing operator [] and pass the columns in the desired order.

Here's how you can do it:

```
# create a copy of the original dataframe
df2 = df1.copy()

# interchange the columns
df2 = df2[['col2', 'col1']]
```

The above code creates a copy of the original dataframe df1 and then passes a list of column names ['col2', 'col1'] to the indexing operator []. This will create a new dataframe df2 with columns col2 and col1 in the desired order.

You can also chain the above code in a single line:

```
df2 = df1[['col2', 'col1']].copy()
```

This will directly select the desired columns from df1 and create a copy of the resulting dataframe with the columns interchanged.

In either case, the resulting dataframe df2 will have the columns col2 and col1 in the desired order.